# Find dynamically added class and apply css on it

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have dynamically add "draggable" class to div element. Now i wants to find it in my parent div and put some css on it. 
My Code is

```
const eDrag = document.querySelector(".draggable");
            eDrag.style.left = widthValue;
```

But It is giving error i.e. Property 'style' does not exist on type 'Element'

Comment: Could it be that you have more than one element with the class .draggable?

Comment: No. Only one element

Comment: what happens if  you write eDrag[0].style.left = widthValue; ?

Comment: Now Cannot read property 'style' of undefined error is coming.  console.log(eDrag ) is giving null.

Comment: Are you sure that your element with class .draggable is created when you call your code?

Comment: Yes , draggable class is there. Is there any another way to find the class and then apply css on it?